# github.com/elastic/helm-charts: How to get external url of Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I use the chart https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts, version 7.7.1 installed elasticsearch, kibana and logstash into Kubernetes cluster. helm version is 2.16.10. Kubernetes version is 1.16 (eks). I use default settings.

```
Commands to install:
helm install --name elasticsearch ./elasticsearch --namespace elk
helm install --name kibana ./kibana --namespace elk
helm install --name logstash ./logstash --namespace elk
```

How to get the external URL of Kibana? If I need to configure loadBalancer, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the service type in [values.yaml](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/kibana/values.yaml) to LoadBalancer instead of a ClusterIP.

```
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Alternatively you can also set a parameter's value  using --set while running the install command.

```
helm install --name kibana ./kibana --namespace elk --set service.type="LoadBalancer"
```

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer so that it can be useful for others as well :)